# How to decipher entity relationships in a Physical Data Model given the corresponding Logical Data Model

Tags: database-design, erd

Can someone use the entity relationships in this Logical Data Model (LDM):

[image: Logical Data Model]

to explain the entity relationships in this Physical Data Model (PDM):

[image: Physical Data Model]

- and how to specify the foreign keys in the PDM?

Comment: Why the images are not visible in my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your question...

That said, lemme try to help you.

I undestand the model represents the categorization of 'parties' as begin part of 'segments'. These categorizations are mutable and have to be traceable in time.

Let me humbly present what I think is a more complete LDM, where

- `PARTY` is explicited
- `Segment Group Cd` is exported as part of the *identifying* relationship (a solid line)
- the verbs sentences are more verbose

[image: Better (?) LDM]

From this LDM, the straightest derived 3NF (3rd Normal Form) PDM should be (`PARTY` entity not shown):

[image: Straightest possible 3NF PDM derivation from LDM]

The PDM you posted:

1. is ***denormalized*** - `MRKT_SGMNT_GROUP` comprises both `MRKT_SGMNT` and `MRKT_SGMNT_GROUP` entities
2. is ***incomplete*** - it's missing `Party_Sgmnt_End_Dttm`
3. states ***redundant relationships*** - the two relationships are the same
4. or, more formalistically, states an ***incorrect relationship*** - the *identifying* relationship (the one represented as a solid line) yelds both key properties from `MRKT_SEGMNT_GROUP` as key properties to `PARTY_SGMNT_HIST`, which aren't - just `Sgmnt_Id` has been derived as part of the PK

With the denormalization presented, the PDM ought to be, with the missing property marked in bold red:

[image: Correct, denormalized PDM]

Did this serve as any help? Hope so...

Regards, Marcus Vinicius.